# How do you align inputs (with labels) with a button on the same line?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Just trying to make an easy-to-use search form by having all elements inline. It looks like the label pushes the inputs down by about 14px or so, but there's nothing to do the same for the search button. Any ideas on how I can get everything on the same line?

[image: Screenshot]

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <label>Date: </label>
        <input type="date" name="startdate" class="form-control"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <label>Optional Search String: </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to put any tricks bootstrap already has a class for such scenario which is [form-inline](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline). You can use it in your requirement. I have modified your classes according to that.

```
<div class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Date: </label>
        <input type="date" name="startdate" class="form-control"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Optional Search String: </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control"/>
    </div>
  <div class="form-group" style="vertical-align:bottom">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have just use the `vertical-align:bottom` with last `form-group` because you have only one element in the last group instead of having two in rest of them.

**[Demo](http://bootply.com/111796)**

Comment: This puts labels to the left of the fields. I don't believe that is the right solution for the original question.

Answer (score 1):

One trick is to add a hidden `label` before your `button`:

```
<label class="hiddenLabel">This is hidden label</label>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
```

then you can apply `visibility: hidden;` to this hidden label.

**[Bootply Demo](http://bootply.com/111793)**

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there's any bootstrap class that specific, but it's easy to do yourself, using a `margin-top: 14px` on the button

Answer (score 0):

```
             <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <label>Date: </label>
                        <input type="date" name="startdate" class="form-control"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <label>Optional Search String: </label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-top: 28px">
                            Search
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
```